# Can OpenStreetMap display train stations?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps

I do not have a car and I move around on a bicycle. I thus often need to know what the closest train station is to a location I need to go to.

I notice that OpenStreetMap (OSM) displays airports in an obvious way, such as [here](http://www.openstreetmap.org/index.html?mlat=44.975278&mlon=1.323333&zoom=10&layers=Q).

Is there a way to have OSM (or Google Maps) display train stations in a more obvious way than having to zoom in enough on each city in an area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a specific transports map in [OpenStretMap website](http://www.openstreetmap.org/index.html?layers=T)

Comment: The OSM cycle map, available at the same link, also gives Trains station location at relatively low zooming (5km in the graphic scale), plus it has relief information, that can be quite handy for someone riding a bike.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I was thinking of a big icon that looked like a train, but displaying the names is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just type Train Station near 1927 foo st, foo city  or wherever you are. This method works well on Google maps. Also you could extract train stations from the OSM database and make your own map. To learn more about extracting OSM data, a quick stack exchange or search engine search should put in you the right location.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It works for big stations, but it missed some smaller stations.